# How to show json after ajax success?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a query in my controller and it returns data in json format,now I'm trying to show the returned data in view using ajax and jQuery. But every time the output is :[object Object]. I'm looking for mistakes, if anyone can help...

This is the ajax code

```
<script>
    $('#sub').click(function () {
        var date1=$('#date1').val();
        var date2=$('#date2').val();
        var token=$('#token').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
        $.ajax
        ({

            url:"{{Url('showJobTime')}}",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{'date1':date1,'date2':date2,'_token':token,'id':id},
            success:function(response)
            {

                alert(response);//the output is object Object
                //alert('success');
                $.each(response,function(index,element){
                    $('#show').text({text:element.time1});
                 });

            },error:function (error) {

                alert('error');
               // console.log(error);

            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

and this is controller

```
 public function searchJobTime()
{

    $inputs=Request::all();
    $date1=$inputs['date1'];
    $date2=$inputs['date2'];
    $data=DB::table('consultant_timings')->whereNotBetween('date',[$date2,$date1])->get();
    return response()->json($data);

}
```

Comment: instead of alert(response) try console.log(response) and tell us the output please

Comment: I used console.log(response) but there was nothing as output

Comment: Just found out what is causing this behavior. Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your back end is returning nothing to the front end. Try using [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) instead of return. Using echo, you will actually write the json so the browser can read it. If you do not, you will be returning the json string to whatever is calling the searchJobTime() function, and not writing it to the browser.

```
public function searchJobTime()
{

    $inputs=Request::all();
    $date1=$inputs['date1'];
    $date2=$inputs['date2'];
    $data=DB::table('consultant_timings')->whereNotBetween('date',[$date2,$date1])->get();
    echo response()->json($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alert use
 `console.log(response);` 
In dev tools you can see the structure of the returned Jon object.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an array of objects, you should use `console.log(response)`  instead of alert

Comment: I used console.log(response) but there is nothing to show

Answer (score 0):

I used console.log(response[0]) to find what the output is as dear friends said...and used $.each() jquery method to show data in view as below

and again if anyone correct above description I would appreciate...

the ajax code

```
<script>
    $('#sub').click(function () {
        var date1=$('#date1').val();
        var date2=$('#date2').val();
        var token=$('#token').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })
        $.ajax
        ({

            url:"{{Url('showJobTime')}}",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{'date1':date1,'date2':date2,'_token':token},
            success:function(response)
            {
                //alert('success');
                //console.log(response[0]);
                $('#change').empty();
                $.each(response,function(key,value){
                      $('#change').append(
                          "<tr  class='odd gradeX'>"+
                                "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' value='1' /></td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone' id='firstName'>"+value.date+"</td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone' id='lastName'>"+value.date+"</td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone' id='date'>"+value.date+"</td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone' id='time1'>"+value.time1+"</td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone' id='time2'>"+value.time2+"</td>"+
                                "<td class='hidden-phone'><span class='label label-success'>Approved</span></td>"+
                        "</tr>");
                    });

            },error:function (error) {

                alert('error');
               // console.log(error);
            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

and controller code

```
  public function searchJobTime()
{

    $inputs=Request::all();
    $date1=$inputs['date1'];
    $date2=$inputs['date2'];
    $data=DB::table('consultant_timings')->whereBetween('date',[$date2,$date1])->get();
    return response()->json($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#form_id").serialize()` instead of `var date1=$('#date1').val();
        var date2=$('#date2').val();
        var token=$('#token').val();`

Comment: would you explain more?

Comment: $("#form_id").serialize() is a way to avoid pass each parameter by hand

Comment: if you want to get the combined html you want you can use heredoc But that's not the best practice. here is an example:https://github.com/asyncpjax/didactic-sniffle/blob/master/heredoc.php